# How to increase font size?

Tags: css, html

I am editing a website template which has the following css for a button class.

```
.button {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0.35em;
    border: solid 3px #efefef;
    color: #787878 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 6.15em;
    height: calc(2.75em + 6px);
    line-height: 2.75em;
    min-width: 20em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin:10px;

}
```

I am trying to increase the font within. Tried playing around with the values of line-height and height but wasn't able to increase the font size. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `font-size`?

Comment: try `size: 10px` or `font-size: 10px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `font-size:__px`  whatever pixel value it is

Answer (score 1):

I just added **font-size** property to CSS. It worked. Pretty Basic :P

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is utilize the CSS font-size property:

```
#yourdiv{
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
size: 20px;
```

or:

```
font-size: 20px;
```